# Hide Button based on OS

Tags: macos, ipad

I am writing an app for both iPad and for it to run on MacOS, so far it's working great in migrating to MacOS.

However I wish to hide a button or at least disable the button if it's running on the mac, but allow it to be enabled if running on the iPad or iPhone.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are try to run on macCatalyst than you can use this code

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    print("Disable or hide your button")
#elseif os(watchOS)
    print("for watchOS")
#else
    print("enable your button")
#endif
```